# How to plot pdf at the same graph as the histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

I wrote a function to plot a histogram of the following data(shortened)

```
data_1 = 
[0.68417915 0.53041328 0.05499373 0.32483917 0.30501979 0.12136537
 0.22964997 0.5837272  0.06000122 0.69908738 0.15690346 0.20363323
 0.10390346 0.98658757 0.98359924 0.29493355 0.72561782 0.75613625
 0.69628136 0.71322217 0.63060554 0.91118187 0.14915375 0.70929528
 0.42408604 0.35388851 0.62253336 0.63676291 0.44358184 0.45063505
 0.36477958 0.15807182 0.714753   0.96713497 0.4094859  0.56495619
 0.57509395 0.9355384  0.46284749 0.67779101 0.92363017 0.05682404
 0.89631817 0.52587218 0.79428246 0.14486141 0.31300898 0.10176549
 0.21841843 0.25688406 0.55415834 0.84957183 0.76246304 0.98489949
 0.3936749  0.51460251 0.50138111 0.36060756 0.44854838 0.3919771
 0.05113578 0.23980216 0.96111616 0.05969004 0.63652018 0.77869691
 0.74565952 0.53789898 0.8876854  0.02370424 0.75647449 0.1494505
 0.56362217 0.84942793 0.75265825 0.43319662 0.1012875  0.09946243
 0.69463561 0.46931918 0.12913483 0.22142044 0.77253391 0.1691685
 0.41114265 0.011321   0.41941435 0.28070956 0.65810948 0.58770776
 0.68763623 0.36828773 0.70466821 0.8332811  0.12652526 0.16867114
 0.59106388 0.56926637 0.87954323 0.62176163 7.35566843e-01 
 1.00146415e-01 6.68137620e-01 4.39246138e-01
 3.75875260e-01 2.12544712e-02 3.68062161e-01 5.35692768e-01
 6.50231419e-01 7.51573475e-01 1.43792206e-01 3.51057868e-01
 1.77127799e-03 9.88480387e-01 8.73988015e-01 3.78791845e-01
 5.89179323e-01 4.05978444e-01 6.88178816e-01 8.73515486e-01
 3.66033185e-01 7.98291151e-01 2.30921252e-01 8.68201375e-04
 4.92515713e-01 4.56100036e-01 5.66357689e-01 1.18801303e-01
 8.15197293e-01 1.90998886e-02 4.91136435e-01 4.90613456e-01
 1.31219088e-01 8.44170500e-01 1.72284226e-01 9.48296215e-01
 7.36638954e-01 2.23674369e-01 7.46383520e-02 1.56815967e-01
 6.14167905e-02 9.55175567e-01 1.74517808e-01 6.16529512e-01
 7.02704931e-01 2.17204373e-01 6.78545848e-01 8.99756168e-01
 5.28857712e-01 8.34009864e-01 5.87747412e-01 9.01901813e-02
 9.94429960e-01 8.20847209e-01 3.88627889e-01 7.99302264e-01
 1.19291073e-01 3.92748464e-01 4.84674232e-01 6.86047613e-01
 9.09811416e-01 4.11619033e-01 5.22738580e-01 7.87679969e-01
 8.31886542e-01 5.75564445e-01 7.03306890e-01 4.37121850e-01
 2.17908948e-01 9.27734103e-01 1.69151398e-01 1.02815443e-01
 8.86529746e-01 9.12471508e-01 3.62394360e-02 5.75760637e-01
 9.02910130e-01 9.46808438e-01 5.22324825e-01 7.41599515e-02
 1.67554744e-01 9.67044492e-01 6.41305316e-02 2.02375526e-01
 7.87664750e-01 4.10928526e-01 3.75066800e-01 1.02825038e-01
 7.99960722e-01 5.15931793e-01 6.07891990e-01 4.22650890e-01
 2.50692729e-01 4.76696332e-01 3.42881458e-01 4.56350909e-01
 2.21493003e-02 9.22045389e-01 4.31748031e-01 3.67451551e-01]
```

And the following code

```
def plot_histo(data_list, bin_count):
    plt.hist(data_list, bins=bin_count, density= True)
    return plt.show()

plot_1 = plot_histo(data_1, 100)
```

I also want to plot the pdf of this distribution on the same graph, but i don't really know how to do that since I'm new to python! Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to estimate the pdf from the samples.

One way is to use kernel density estimation, which can be done easily with [`sns.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html).

Another way is to fit parameters of a known distribution, e.g. with scikit-learn [`GaussianMixture`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html) if you have reasons to think your data is gaussian.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

num_samples = 1_000
mu = 3.14
sigma = 1.27

data = np.random.randn(num_samples) * sigma + mu

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Histogram
ax.hist(data, bins=10, density=True, label="Histogram")

# Kernel Density Estimation (KDE)
sns.kdeplot(data, bw_method=0.2, ax=ax, label="KDE")

# Gaussian fitting
gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=1).fit(data.reshape(-1, 1))
mu_ = gm.means_.item()
sigma_ = gm.covariances_.item()
xx = np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim(), num=100)
plt.plot(xx, stats.norm.pdf(xx, mu_, sigma_), label="Gaussian")

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: pdf estimation]